# How to display First Name and Last Name instead of email _LoginPartial

Tags: asp.net-core

am building a web application using ASP.NET CORE 3.0(razor pages), I extended my **IdentityUser** by adding first name and last name field, and I want display the both fields in place of email in **_loginPartial** here is my Class

```
public partial class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }       
}
```

Here is where am calling the username

```
 <li>
       <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post">
                                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

I am not sure of how to get FirstName and LastName in place of User.Identity.Name.
please I need help.

Comment: Have you checked the `User.Claims` property?

Comment: I have no idea if am to add to user.claim, I just thought I could get it from the aspnetuser table directly.

Answer (score 2):

in

> _LoginPartial.cshtml

file replace

```
@UserManager.GetUserName(User)
```

with

```
@UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.FirstName
```

and

```
@UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.LastName
```

---

```
  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp- area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.FirstName  @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.LastName </a>
            </li>
```

[image: final result]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve that is to add it to `ViewData` like this:
In your `Account` controller on the `Manage index` view

```
// read the application user from db
var user = dbContext.Users...
ViewData["UserFirstName"] = user.FirstName;
ViewData["LastName"] = user.LastName;
```

And then in your view just read those values from `ViewData`

```
<div> 
  Hello @ViewData["UserFirstName"] @ViewData["UserLastName"] 
</div>
```

Another approach is to add a model to your view; here are some good docs that you can read:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Okay, thanks for you reply am actually using Blazor, no controller, it's just razor pages and components and I want to display the name in Logindisplay.razor and _LoginPartial.